# How to add custom lint rules in create-react-app without ejecting the boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, eslintrc

I'm trying to add custom lint rules on top of the lint rules that come out of the box with create-react-app. Doing so throws error about versioning issue of certain lint packages while running the build.

Answer (score 0):

Create new files `.eslintrc` and add following code. You can customize the rules as required.

```js
{
  "extends": ["equimper", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "experimentalDecorators":"true"
  }
}
```

Also add following packages as dev depencency. You can modify as required. `*` will install latest version in this case.

```js
 "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "*",
    "eslint-config-equimper": "*",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "*",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "*",
    "prettier": "*"
  }
```